# Data from child window

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar

In the imported code, the variable '*values*' is set correctly with the date selected by the user.

The def **selection** is called at the exit of the calendar.

I'm stuck. I don't know how to catch it and use it in my main code.

Thanks a lot.

```
# MAIN CODE (simplified)
from tkinter import *
import calendarWidget    
def manageCalendarWindow():
    root4 = Tk()
    data = {}
    app = calendarWidget.Calendar(root4, data)
    root4.mainloop()
manageCalendarWindow()
#how to get the date?
```

-.-.-.-.-.-.-.

```
# CALENDAR WIDGET (simplified)
class Calendar:
    def setup(self, y, m)
        (...)
        for w, week in enumerate(self.cal.monthdayscalendar(y, m), 2):
            for d, day in enumerate(week):
                if day:
                    b = tk.Button(self.parent, width=1, text=day, relief = 'flat',\
                    command=lambda day=day:self.selection(day, calendar.day_name[(day-1) % 7]))
                    self.wid.append(b)
                    b.grid(row=w, column=d)

    def selection(self, day, name):
        self.day_selected = day
        self.month_selected = self.month
        self.year_selected = self.year
        self.day_name = name

        #data
        self.values['day_selected'] = day
        self.values['month_selected'] = self.month
        self.values['year_selected'] = self.year
        self.values['day_name'] = name
        self.values['month_name'] = calendar.month_name[self.month_selected]

        self.setup(self.year, self.month)
        print(self.values) # <--- here the value is correct
        self.parent.destroy()
```

-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-

## THIS WORKS:

```
def manageCalendarWindow():
    root4 = Tk()
    data = {}
    app = calendarWidget.Calendar(root4, data)
    root4.mainloop()
    return app    
app=manageCalendarWindow()
print(app.year_selected,app.month_selected,app.day_selected)
```

## THIS NOT:

```
class enterWindows():
    def B_CalendarWindow(self):`
        app=self.manageCalendarWindow()
        print("year: ",app.year_selected)
        print("and... this will never be printed!")

    def manageCalendarWindow(self):
        root4 = Tk()
        data = {}
        app = calendarWidget.Calendar(root4, data)
        root4.mainloop()
        return app
```

Comment: Your comment that the "def selection method is called at the exit of the calendar" sounds key. Can you include the context in which "selection" is called? It sounds like that's where the problem might be.

Comment: I've inserted the code of the button with which **selection** is invoked. Thanks, Ron. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, there can be only one **mainloop** in the code. The others will be simply ignored. So it's not possible to use it to wait for a response from a child window.

The solution I used is

```
    app = myCalendar.Calendar(personal_path, root4, gui_language)
    root4.wait_window(app.parent)
    return app
```

The code opens the window and waits the result using **wait_window()**.

Thanks all.
Ciao.

Comment: Saying other calls to `mainloop` are ignored is wrong. They are definitely _not_ ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Everything local to the function manageCalendarWindow() is garbage collected when the function exits. This includes app (the class instance).  You would have to return it to keep it alive.  Note also that there is no self.month in the code you posted but I assume that comes from cutting the amount of code back for this post.

```
def manageCalendarWindow():
    root4 = Tk()
    data = {}
    app = calendarWidget.Calendar(root4, data)
    root4.mainloop()
    return app
    ## or
    ## return app.day_name
app=manageCalendarWindow()
print(app.day_name)
## or
##day_name=manageCalendarWindow()
##print(day_name)
```

Comment: Perfect. what you've suggested to me is perfect and run. But if I put it nested in an other **class**, it stops. I've added the code in tail of the others.

Comment: print("and... this will never be printed!")  Nothing will be printed until you exit Tkinter.

Comment: And check that you actually have a value in self.year_selected, i.e print a message when/where it is created/updated in class Calendar, and it's value.

Comment: I know, Curly. I know... But really, I have no idea how get this date... Why, if I call the Calendar inside a Class, the variable **app** is empty.

Answer (score 1):

A simple proof-of concept program that gets a variable from a class instantiated within the class.

```
class SubClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable="SubClass variable"

class MainClass():
    def __init__(self):
        app=self.instantiate_class()
        print(app.variable)  ## prints the string

    def instantiate_class(self):
        app=SubClass()
        print("app =", app)  ## not empty
        return app

MainClass()
```

Comment: Hi Joe. 

I've think I've found the problem. 

The window is called from another window and this one from another again: main window > new record window > calendar window. 
So, I learned that, in one program, only one mainloop() can work, the others will be simply ignored. Only the one linked to the main window. No others. 

The program doesn't wait for the result and carry on. It opens the calendar window and isn't able to wait for his result. Or, better, I don't how to suspend the code waiting for the user choice. 

I don't know how to manage this. 
Thanks a lot for your help.
:)